# 画像を大量に保存するiPhoneアプリ

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone

iPhoneアプリ内に画像を大量に保存するアプリを開発中なのですが、かなりメモリ・ストレージを食ってしまいます。
その結果、動作が遅くなったり落ちてしまいます。

アプリ内に画像を大量に保存する場合はどのような点に注意すればいいのでしょうか。
アドバイスお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

一度使ったオブジェクトを初期化してメモリーにゴミをためない事を意識してプログラミングすることをやってみてください

Answer (score 2):

#### 表示時

UICollectionView, UITableView等を使う。
生成したViewが使い回しされメモリ消費を抑えられるので。

#### 保存・保持時

保存対象データ(NSData)への参照を残さないようにし、ファイル保存後すぐ開放されるようにする。

データ内容丸ごとをインスタンスで保持しないようにする。

ループ処理内でデータ取得やファイル保存する際にはループ内を@autoreleasepoolで囲う。

#### その他

気を付ける点はざっくり以上ですが、問題箇所を知ることも重要です。

Xcode付属のProfileツールを使うことでメモリ使用状況を可視化できます。
実際にメモリ消費が増えている箇所見つけ対応していきましょう。

メモリリークは言わずもがな、潰しておきましょう。